# Why value of input list is getting changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I don't know what title should be given to my this confusion so I'm putting it just a doubt

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a 

for i in range(len(a)):
    c = (i - 4)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    b[c] = a[i]
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5]
...
```

why values of list `a` is getting in each step of loop?

Comment: Your code does not run as `b` is not defined. Please can you check / update.

Comment: I've made required edit.

Comment: Change ```b = a``` to  ```b = list(a)```. The way you did just make ```a``` and ```b``` just point to the same array.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
b = a
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. In particular, it does *not* make a copy of `a`. After the assignment, both `b` and `a` refer to the same object. Thus, any change to `b` is reflected in `a` also.

One way to force a shall copy is to use the slice syntax:

```
b = a[:]
```

Comment: Thanx man, doubt cleared

Comment: But please study the duplicate questions. The answers there are much more revealing than my answer here.